# evoPDF export from Angular & .NET

Tags: angularjs, evopdf

We are trying to export a PDF of our HTML page which is rendered using Angular. The PDF which is currently being produced contains the static content but none of the Angular requested data.

Upon trying to debug this we placed break points in each of the server side functions which should be called within the .Net controller. They aren't being called.

Is there a way we can debug the evoPDF part to try and work out what is going on? It's as if the NG-View isn't being kicked off or rendered for some reason but we have no way of working out why

```
byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlToPdf);
// This is the call we are using to grab the PDF of the HTML the PDF is generated its just mostly empty.
```

Any help on how we can debug this would be greatly appreciated. Due to the fact its using GetPdfBytesFromUrl we can't place break points in the angular as its not called from the browser!.

For information we are using evoPDF v7.0 
The back end is C# MVC

Comment: We used pdfMake (http://pdfmake.org/) and it works like a charm.

Comment: That tool doesn't perform HTML to PDF it requires you to define the PDF in a Javascript definition file format.

Comment: It turns out this was a version issue of Evo and upgrade fixed the issue.